# Devstack deploy openstack Failed to start iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid)

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, devstack

I use devstack to deploy openstack by the documentation ([devstack documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/))

It failed like this:

```
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up open-iscsi (2.0.873+git0.3b4b4500-14ubuntu3.3) ...
Job for iscsid.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status iscsid.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript iscsid, action "start" failed.
* iscsid.service - iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iscsid.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Thu 2017-06-08 01:26:49 UTC; 6ms ago
     Docs: man:iscsid(8)
  Process: 16691 ExecStart=/sbin/iscsid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16686 ExecStartPre=/lib/open-iscsi/startup-checks.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 08 01:26:49 localhost systemd[1]: Starting iSCSI initiator daemon (iscs.....
Jun 08 01:26:49 localhost iscsid[16691]: iSCSI logger with pid=16692 started!
Jun 08 01:26:49 localhost systemd[1]: iscsid.service: Failed to read PID fr...nt
Jun 08 01:26:49 localhost iscsid[16692]: iSCSI daemon with pid=16693 started!
Jun 08 01:26:49 localhost iscsid[16692]: can not create NETLINK_ISCSI socket
Jun 08 01:26:49 localhost systemd[1]: iscsid.service: Daemon never wrote it...g.
Jun 08 01:26:49 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start iSCSI initiator daemo...).
Jun 08 01:26:49 localhost systemd[1]: iscsid.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 08 01:26:49 localhost systemd[1]: iscsid.service: Failed with result 'r...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package open-iscsi (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/sda
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
Errors were encountered while processing:
 open-iscsi
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
+functions-common:apt_get:1                exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:492                  local r=100
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:493                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:493                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:496                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:502                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:388               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:504                  [[ 100 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:505                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:506                  generate-subunit 1496885135 78 fail
./stack.sh: line 506: generate-subunit: command not found
```

I use the linode vps,and the os is ubuntu16.04LTS with the kernel of 4.8.3-x86_64-linode76

by the way, I have tried centos 7 on linode vps and encoutered the same problem, totally the same. 
What should i do ?

Comment: It looks like iscsid is not starting correctly. Do you have an "iscsid.socket" service? If so, is it enabled and started? If so, that might be the problem. If not, then it's something else.

Other possibilities: do you have an iscsid already running? It looks like just creating the socket is failing. That isn't normal, unless (1) you are not root, (2) the system is out of memory, or (3) there is already somebody using that socket (like another iscsid).

Comment: Also, can you include your iscsid.service systemd unit file?